# What young adult series involved a club of boys who bought a submarine?

Tags: identification-request, mystery-novels

I recall a series of young adult or children book, but cannot find the name about a group of boys who solved a detective club of sorts. They solved mysteries or other problems in their community.

- In one book, they helped solve a case involving a missing treasure that was placed in the barrel of a cannon.
- In another book, they bought a submarine, by bidding down instead of up, and used it to explore a local lake.
- In another book, they helped locate a lost parachute jumper.

Does anyone know the name of this series?

Comment: There's a [Hardy Boys story](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/76968.The_Secret_of_Pirates_Hill) involving a cannon and a diving expedition, but it's not exactly what you describe. Does Hardy Boys in general, or [Three Investigators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Investigators), sound at all familiar to you?

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to be that series. I think the series I am looking for only had about 4-6 books. In the cannon story, they were searching for something stolen, and realized that some thief had thrown it into the barrel of a cannon in town square before it was filled with concrete and the money or treasure was there for many years.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*The Mad Scientists' Club* series by Bertrand R. Brinley

*The Mad Scientists' Club*:

> A strange sea monster suddenly appears on Strawberry Lake, a fortune
>   is unearthed from an old cannon and a valuable dinosaur egg is stolen.
>   Who's responsible? Those seven junior geniuses -- and their wild
>   ideas. Watch out as the Mad Scientists' Club turns the town of Mammoth
>   Falls upside down!

Quote from the [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=63oyOh6jgbEC&pg=PT58&dq=Hidden%20%22in%20the%20cannon%22%20concrete&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiByoG8kcblAhWpk4sKHaUHAw0Q6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=Hidden%20%22in%20the%20cannon%22%20concrete&f=false):

> “You mean you think the bank robber hid the money in the cannon, and
>   then before he could get it out again the Town Council sent a crew out
>   there to plug up the barrel with cement?

*The New Adventures of the Mad Scientists' Club*:

> A secret cavern becomes the perfect spot to restore a midget
>   submarine, bank robbers must be apprehended, a flying sorcerer looms
>   over Mammoth Falls and that's just the beginning of five more mad, mad
>   MAD adventures!!